# iTunes Connect Error 3000 / Cannot upload IPA with Application Loader

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, xcode6.3, application-loader

> Original [Apple Developer Forum post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1133109).

I'm using Application Loader to upload a hosted IAP (I've done this many times before).

However after the package passes validation I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR ITMS-3000: "Line 91 column 52: element "in_app_purchase" incomplete; missing required element "product_id""
```

[image: ERROR ITMS-3000: Line 91 column 52: element in_app_purchase" incomplete; missing required element product_id]

The IAP target has a `IAPProductIdentifier` and it is also set up on iTunes Connect.

Am I missing something or is the upload system down?

Comment: Do you have an option to upload it via Xcode?

Comment: @Mike.R Uploading IAP in Xcode has never worked (for me).

Comment: Why? what was the error?
did u see that thread: https://discussions.apple.com/message/21552770#21552770
Sorry looks like "ERROR ITMS-3000:" respond to several errors